# MVVMLight installs one version of assembly, but references different version

Tags: mvvm-light, wpf-4.0

MVVMLight 4.3.31.28629 in WPF project, VS2013.
The MVVMLight install (via nuget) added Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation 1.2.0.0.
Inspecting MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4, I find this:
[image]

My application runs in the debugger, but not when launched from the command line.  (It throws an exception from the ViewModelLocator ctor, trying to find Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation 1.0.0.0.)
Why does it run inside the debugger, and how do I fix it to run outside the debugger?
Thanks --

**UPDATE**
What the hell?  Why are two versions of the same assembly referenced?

```
        at ProdoMetro.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator..ctor()
   InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException
        HResult=-2146234304
        Message=Could not load file or assembly **Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.2.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
        Source=TimerDoro
        FileName=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
        FusionLog=""
        StackTrace:
             at ProdoMetro.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator..cctor()
        InnerException: System.IO.FileLoadException
             HResult=-2146234304
             Message=Could not load file or assembly **Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
             FileName=Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
             FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

(Fully-specified)

Comment: I have tried uninstalling and re-installing MVVMLight via nuget -- MVVM Light Libs only, MVVM Light Toolkit, with no success in getting the app to run.

Comment: What happens if you create a new project from scratch and install MVVM Light? Still get the same error?